# The document “File.scn” could not be saved

Tags: xcode

I just added a `.dae` file to my application then convert it to `.scn`, but I cannot save any changes and I get this error constantly when I try to save any changes:

[image]

I searched and tried many ways from changing permission, rebooting system and etc... but still couldn't any solution, how should fix this issue?

Comment: how did you convert it to .scn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternate solution is to create a new project, move the file to new one, edit it and then move it back to the current project.!