# The document “filename.dae” could not be saved

Tags: xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, assets, arkit

I checked all possible solutions, including:

- Rebooting Mac
- Change red/write permission from get_info window.
- change read/write permission from terminal using 'sudo chmod command'
- Also tried with [this command](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109669#335313).
- Check by creating new project and make changes in it by referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324262/8061359).
- Also tried to login as guest user.

But nothing works, Anyone facing problem like this in SceneKit with ARKit project.

I know there are multiple questions posted but none of them are working for me.

Can anyone suggest if there is any solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Error in Xcode 10.2.1]

Answer (score 1):

Create the new .scn file in the .scnassets folder, then drag the .dae file into the scene.

Or

[image: You can direct convert .dae file to .scn]

Comment: hmm, Let me check with it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627965/how-to-convert-dae-to-scn-files-in-scenekit

Answer (score 0):

The best working solution, in this case, will be a conversion of your `.dae`, `.abc` or `.obj` model into [.usdz](https://medium.com/techinpieces/all-about-apples-new-usdz-file-format-simplified-12dff29f3fc0) file format. Doing so, you can easily use an animated and realistically textured `.usdz` model within ARKit, SceneKit and RealityKit modules.

Here's what Pixar says about its own `.usd` file format:

> USD provides multiple features that could make it a compelling choice for 3D content delivery, including:
>
> - Robust schemas for interchange of geometry, shading, and skeletal deformation
> - High performance data retrieval and rendering, including powerful instancing features
> - The ability to package user-selectable content variations, natively
> - A sound architecture that is flexible enough to adapt to future needs
>
> (`USDZ package is a zero compression, unencrypted zip archive`.)

*Look at* [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-10-converter/50867018#50867018) *and* [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544185/how-to-generate-usdz-file-again-from-zip-file/55631922#55631922) *to find out how to make a conversion*.

**P.S.**

When converting DAE into USDZ you need Pythonic `usdz Tools` and Xcode 11.0 installed.

When converting OBJ into USDZ you need Xcode 10.3 installed. But remember OBJ doesn't support animation.